# Removing specific cells in fishnet based on certain criteria using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

[image]

I have created a fishnet over my study area, the grid cell size is 0.5 x 0.5 degrees. Red and Blue points represents summer/winter sightings of certain species, is there a way to remove the cells based on different criteria, such as:

1. Must have consecutive winter sightings by year
2. More than X number of sightings

I performed spatial join between the two layer but not sure about the query here.

Comment: I think you should look at the Select tool in the Analysis toolbox.

Comment: Removing cells isn't best practice here. Instead, Select By Location and copy the selected cells to a new table. Counting the sightings is a better match for Overlay functions like Intersect.

Comment: Ok. I'll try using the select tool.

Comment: But how would I specify that there has to be AT LEAST 2 points in a cell if the spatial joint was 'one to many' (the join_count is not unique since its always 1).

Comment: To get a count on each cell of how many points are in it you may be able to use Spatial Join but I prefer using Intersect , Frequency then Join Field.

Comment: Ok Thanks! I'll try that too!

Comment: Hmmm Intersection tool didnt work with error message: Invalid topology. Do I have to use a projected coordinate system instead of a geogrpahic one?

Comment: You should probably Repair Geometry first.